# Round Up and Round Down issue in DB

Tags: sql, oracle, vertica

Hi I want to write one function which will round the values like below:

Sample Data

```
select cast(22.5 as decimal(18,0))   --- > 22
select cast(22.51 as decimal(18,0))  --- > 23
select cast(22.49 as decimal(18,0)) --- > 22
```

Am not able to achieve the requirement with round function as its not returning my expected output when value is XX.5

```
select round(22.5) from dual;
Output: 23
But I need here 22.
```

Can anyone please help me to achieve this requirement.

Comment: In your second code block you say that `round(22.5)` gives you 23.  That seems correct according to your first statement when you say `xx.5 -> Round Up`

Comment: ok.. due to some confusion I removed that line.. please help me to achieve the criteria

Comment: Do you want all .5 values to round down, or do you want banker's rounding ( toward even)?

Comment: Can we assume this is a learning exercise, and `ceil`, `floor` and `trunc` cannot be used?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the decimal part with `MOD` in a `CASE` expression and then use `CEIL` or `FLOOR`:

```sql
SELECT value,
       CASE
       WHEN MOD(value, 1) > 0.5
       THEN CEIL(value)
       ELSE FLOOR(value)
       END AS rounded
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT 22.4 + 0.01 * ( LEVEL - 1 )
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 20;
```

Outputs:

> | VALUE | ROUNDED |
> | --- | --- |
> | 22.4 | 22 |
> | 22.41 | 22 |
> | 22.42 | 22 |
> | 22.43 | 22 |
> | 22.44 | 22 |
> | 22.45 | 22 |
> | 22.46 | 22 |
> | 22.47 | 22 |
> | 22.48 | 22 |
> | 22.49 | 22 |
> | 22.5 | 22 |
> | 22.51 | 23 |
> | 22.52 | 23 |
> | 22.53 | 23 |
> | 22.54 | 23 |
> | 22.55 | 23 |
> | 22.56 | 23 |
> | 22.57 | 23 |
> | 22.58 | 23 |
> | 22.59 | 23 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=186ff347c26eea57a8d1dc0192d93e40)*

Answer (score 0):

First, you cannot do what you specify in the question.  `decimal(18, 0)` has no decimal points.  So the three values are simply 23, 23, and 22, with no decimal points.  Let me assume that you intend `decimal(18, 2)` as the data type.

I would suggest:

```
select ceil(val + 0.5) - 1
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b8380aeae23ccfcbc5efa5e3d73722f8) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is decimal(18,0) will not convert it to a valid decimal, it will convert into an integer. I think it is better you cast it to an integer, but casting it to any integer will convert all the values between 23.1 and 23.9 to 23 which will not work in your case. There is a ROUND function but it will convert as below

select ROUND(22.51)  --- > 23 -- ROUND will round up the decimal to the next higher number is it ends with .5

So the best solution for your case is FLOOR. FLOOR will round down to the next lowest value if the number end with 0.5

select FLOOR(22.51)  --- > 22